# Join to get most specific record for tenant without PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, join

I have a `Settings` table and a `Tenant` table.
There is a hierarchy for that an `Account` can have 1 or many `Companies` and a `Company` can have 1 or many `Facilities'.

```
Account 1
   ---> Company 1
          ---> Facility 1   
          ---> Facility 2
   ---> Company 2
          ---> Facility 3   
          ---> Facility 4
```

They may have a default setting that applies to their entire account....

```
| FacilityId | CompanyId | AccountId | SettingValue |
|------------|-----------|-----------|--------------|
|     (null) |    (null) |         1 |            5 |
```

...except they have one override for Facility 3 that only applies to Facility 3, all other facilities will use the default setting value at the account level.

```
| FacilityId | CompanyId | AccountId | SettingValue |
|------------|-----------|-----------|--------------|
|          3 |    (null) |         1 |            6 |
```

I want to create a join between them to get the *most specific* setting for each tenant. *Most specific* is defined as the `Setting` record that matches the `Tenant`'s `FacilityId` is more specific than a match on `CompanyId` which is more specific than a match on `AccountId` and finally, if no match is found, use the setting that has `NULL` for all 3 values.

I do not want to use the `PIVOT` feature as the code uses Entity Framework and LINQ and there is no LINQ to SQL for `PIVOT`. Basically need simple SQL that you could create a view for...so no temp tables, etc. Not looking for a stored proc solution if at all possible.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63dc85/1)

Table: `Settings`

```
| FacilityId | CompanyId | AccountId | SettingValue |
|------------|-----------|-----------|--------------|
|          1 |         1 |         1 |            5 |
|     (null) |         2 |         2 |            7 |
|     (null) |         1 |         1 |            4 |
|     (null) |    (null) |         2 |            6 |
|     (null) |    (null) |         1 |            3 |
|     (null) |    (null) |    (null) |            2 |
```

Table: `Tenants`

```
| FacilityId | CompanyId | AccountId |
|------------|-----------|-----------|
|          1 |         1 |         1 |
|          2 |         2 |         2 |
|          3 |         3 |         3 |
```

So join on these would have this desired output:

```
| FacilityId | CompanyId | AccountId | SettingValue |
|------------|-----------|-----------|--------------|
|          1 |         1 |         1 |            5 |
|          2 |         2 |         2 |            7 | --> this account would match to a setting value of 6 or 7, but the 7 value matches more specifically
|          3 |         3 |         3 |            2 | --> there is no match on Facility, Company, or Account so match to all nulls.
```

In code, I am doing the following to get the most specific `Setting` for a given `Tenant`, but I now need to do this for a large set of `Tenant` data and hence want to do it by a SQL Join. For those unfamiliar with LINQ the double pipe (`||`) is equivalent to `OR`.

```
private SettingViewModel GetSettingBy(string strKey)
{
    var allSettings = GetAllSettings();
    var settingQuery = allSettings.Where(x => x.SettingKey == strKey);

    if (_accountCompanyFacilityViewModel.AccountId.HasValue)
    {
        settingQuery = settingQuery.Where(x => (x.AccountId == _accountCompanyFacilityViewModel.AccountId || x.AccountId == null));
    }

    if (_accountCompanyFacilityViewModel.CompanyId.HasValue)
    {
        settingQuery = settingQuery.Where(x => (x.CompanyId == _accountCompanyFacilityViewModel.CompanyId || x.CompanyId == null));
    }

    if (_accountCompanyFacilityViewModel.FacilityId.HasValue)
    {
        settingQuery = settingQuery.Where(x => (x.FacilityId == _accountCompanyFacilityViewModel.FacilityId || x.FacilityId == null));
    }

    var setting = settingQuery
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.FacilityId)
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.CompanyId)
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.AccountId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
            
    return setting;
}
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63dc85/5) for the Answer

Comment: Why do you care if LINQ still doesn't understand what PIVOT means? If LINQ is just consuming the output, and can't handle syntax added in <checks memory> SQL Server 2008, use a stored procedure. LINQ understands those, right? Why limit yourself to a subset of syntax because LINQ is behind?

Comment: @AaronBertrand just preference.  We prefer to limit views/sp's as much as possible for maintenance reasons unless it either can't be done, or the query is so inefficient that the only solution is a DB view or sp.

Comment: That seems pretty subjective. Personally, I find stored procedures a lot _easier_ to deal with for maintenance purposes than having queries littered throughout application code. YMMV. I also don't know of any scenario where taking a query from an application and stuffing it into a view will make anything more efficient aside from the reduction in bytes of network chatter.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes it is subjective. We have common repository classes so we can define these types of queries once and reuse them all over so we don't have the litter. SPs also require an additional element to keep in sync with the application code. They are also a lot more fixed in that they are a set query and result set vs dynamic queries in LINQ. It can be done, but its not as easily. On the performance front, EntityFramework creates really messy and poor performing queries sometimes...we have had great success in rolling our own in that case using indexed views and stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the great data setup. Here's one way to get these hits in SQL.
As Aaron mentioned, this can be a CTE without any varibles.

```
WITH cte AS (
                SELECT  t.AccountId
                        ,t.CompanyId
                        ,t.FacilityId
                        ,CASE
                             WHEN s.AccountId IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                         END + CASE
                                   WHEN s.CompanyId IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                                   ELSE 0
                               END + CASE
                                         WHEN s.FacilityId IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                     END AS HitCount
                        ,s.SettingValue
                FROM    dbo.Tenant AS t
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Settings AS s ON t.FacilityId LIKE ISNULL(CAST(s.FacilityId AS VARCHAR), '%')
                                                             AND   t.CompanyId LIKE ISNULL(
                                                                                              CAST(s.FacilityId AS VARCHAR)
                                                                                              ,'%'
                                                                                          )
                                                             AND   t.AccountId LIKE ISNULL(
                                                                                              CAST(s.AccountId AS VARCHAR)
                                                                                              ,'%'
                                                                                          )
            )
SELECT  t.AccountId
        ,t.CompanyId
        ,t.FacilityId
        ,t.SettingValue
FROM    cte AS t
        CROSS APPLY (
                        SELECT  MAX(t2.HitCount) AS MaxHits
                        FROM    cte AS t2
                        WHERE   t.AccountId = t2.AccountId
                                AND t.CompanyId = t2.CompanyId
                                AND t.FacilityId = t2.FacilityId
                    ) AS hc
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND hc.MaxHits = t.HitCount;
```

Comment: Thanks @FlogDonkey, but looking for a solution that doesn't use temp tables, etc. i.e. something that you could create a view for, not a stored procedure....if possible.

Comment: @Chad You can easily put `@table` in a CTE, there's no reason it has to be a table variable. But that's not going to make it any _faster_, it just makes it possible to convert it to a view definition, which _also_ isn't going to make anything any faster (views are not for speed).

Comment: @AaronBertrand faster is not a requirement as this is a very small data set that will actually be cached in memory in our app.

Comment: Thanks @FlogDonkey. Here's the working SQL Fiddle for reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63dc85/5